# React link isn't working when I click it in the rendered page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm currently using React to build a personal website. I'm using this project as a way to learn React so I'm still very new at this.

I'm using react styled-components to style the page the way I want to, and everything went fine except for a problem I keep having where I can't make links work.

This is my code:

```js
const Mainpage = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Home>
        <WelcomeMessage>My name</WelcomeMessage>
        <UnderText>Software Engineering Student at University</UnderText>
        <Redirect href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
          Link
        </Redirect>
      </Home>
      <About>
        <Header>About me</Header>
      </About>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

In the Redirect tag, I'm setting it as a `<a>` tag in the styled components, however, when I click it in the rendedered page, it doesn't redirect me anywhere. It's the same result as clicking plain text.

This is the code I'm using to style the `Redirect` tag:

```js
export const Redirect = styled.a`
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
`
```

This is my full code in the styled-components file:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

const color = {
    highlight: "#368DF3"
};

export const Wrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5vh;
    z-index: -1;
    margin: 10vh 15vw;
`

export const Home = styled.div`
    margin-right: auto;
`

export const ProfilePic = styled.img`
    scale: 0.3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px black;
`

export const WelcomeMessage = styled.h1`
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 10rem;
    font-family: 'Acme';
    margin: 0;
`

export const UnderText = styled.div`
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: ${props => color.highlight};
`
export const Header = styled.h1`
    color: #eee;
`

export const About = styled.div`
    margin-top: 30vh;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: 'Acme';
`

export const Redirect = styled.a`
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
`
```

Can someone help me understand what the problem is? It's the only issue I'm having so far with React and I haven't been able to find a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed the issue.

The problem was that in `Wrapper` at the styled-components file, I had `z-index: -1;`. Switching this value from `-1` to `0` solved my issue.